# Filter in SSAS cube calculations

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, mdx

How I can create Calculations in Visual Studio with filter on dimensions? For example, I created measure:

```
[Measure].[Sales]
```

it's works for me, but I need to filter result, to show me distinct count on Sales, only for city Berlin. Here is my pseudocode:

```
distinct count(filter([Measure].[Sales], [Geography].[City].&['Berlin']))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct count on Sales"?

Answer (score 0):

[DistinctCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145519.aspx) will return the number of distinct, nonempty tuples in a set.

```
DistinctCount(Nonempty([Measure].[Sales], [Geography].[City].&['Berlin']))
```

Should return the expected outcome.